# How to parse json array using php foreach?

Tags: php, json, foreach

I want to get id,url,img and title of videos in the JSON data.My current code doesn't output anything
could any one tell me what i am doing wrong.Thanks

```
$code2 = stripslashes($_POST['outputtext']);
$data = json_decode($code2, true);
$i = 0;

foreach($data->videos as $values)
{
    echo $values->id . "\n";
    echo $values->url . "\n";
    echo $values->img . "\n";
    echo $values->title . "\n";
$i++;
}
```

data:

```
{
    "cat": {
        "id": "1234567",
        "source_id": null,
        "title_en": "first season",
        "description_en": "This is spring category ",
    },
    "videos": [{
        "id": "312412343",
        "url": "\/2015-07-17\/1abcd.mp4",
        "img": "image\/44\/\/2015-07-17\/1abcd.jpg",
        "title": "first",

    }, {
        "id": "2342343",
        "url": "\/2015-07-16\/2dcdeg.mp4",
        "img": "images\/44\/\/2015-07-16\/2dcdeg.jpg",
        "title": "second",


    }];


}
```

validated json data:

```
{
   "cat":{
      "id":"1234567",
      "source_id":null,
      "title_en":"first season",
      "description_en":"This is spring category "
   },
   "videos":[
      {
         "id":"312412343",
         "url":"\/2015-07-17\/1abcd.mp4",
         "img":"image\/44\/\/2015-07-17\/1abcd.jpg",
         "title":"first"
      },
      {
         "id":"2342343",
         "url":"\/2015-07-16\/2dcdeg.mp4",
         "img":"images\/44\/\/2015-07-16\/2dcdeg.jpg",
         "title":"second"
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: Probably it does not output anything because you try to access an array like an object.

Comment: $data = json_decode($code2, true); return array not object

Comment: your data is not valid json http://json.parser.online.fr/

Comment: Funk Doc . I updated my first post now the json is validated . How to parse the data i want ?

Answer (score 4):

Because you call

```
$data = json_decode($code2, true);
```

your `$data` is an **array** and not an object as you try to access it. So either access it as regular array, or change 2nd argument of `json_decode()` to `false` (or removeit as this is default), as this is what controls conversion behavior.

See docs: http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Your data is not a valid JSON (`;` at the end, redundant and missing comas - it's simply broken).

In case of such problems, `var_dump()` is pretty helpful to inspect what data you are really working with.

Comment: Thanks for replies. Marcin Orlowski i changed the second argument of json_decode to false but still i get no data!

Comment: i used var_dump($data) i get null! so how to get the data i want ?because the method that i use is not working!

Comment: I told you your JSON is invalid in first place!

Comment: i get the data via an api call so how i can parse the data i want if it is not valid json ?

Comment: JSON format is quite strict and PHP will not parse syntactically invalid JSON (check here: https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/ )The one from your question has at least 2 syntax errors. If any API produces this, then the API needs to be fixed. Fixing this JSOn in your code is bad idea.

Comment: Marcin Orlowski i validated (see first post)the json data now the var_dump is not empty it displays the data in array but still foreach doesn't parse the data i want!How to fix that?

Comment: Please read my **whole** answer, especially part related to `json_decode()` and fix your whole code, not just JSON data